# How to set AlertDialog.finish() in the AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am currently using an app that needs to utilize a lot of AlertDialogs. I've currently coded a basic one here:

```
protected void StopButton () {
    AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
    StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
    StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ((Protoype2) getApplication()).setRequestingLocationUpdates(false);
            finish();
        }
    });
    StopDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.No_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((Protoype2) getApplication()).setRequestingLocationUpdates(true);
        }
    });
    StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Closes box
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = StopDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

The StopButton works and the Dialog comes up when I call for it. However, the finish(); function does not work.

Upon review, I found that finish(); did not finish the Dialog, rather the entire app. I know I need to get a AlertDialog.cancel in there.

The problem is this: as you can see, the AlertDialog is only created AFTER the StopDialog is finished.

How can I set an AlertDialog.finish() before StopDialog is finished?

Comment: Do you want to dismiss() it?

Comment: Yes. Is there a difference between finish() and dismiss()?

Comment: finish() will destroy your activity dismiss() will dismiss your dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `finish()` with `dialog.dismiss()` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this);
        StopDialog.setTitle("Title");
        StopDialog.setMessage("Stop");
        StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ((Protoype2) getApplication()).setRequestingLocationUpdates(false);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        StopDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((Protoype2) getApplication()).setRequestingLocationUpdates(true);
            }
        });
        StopDialog.setNeutralButton("Neutral", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Closes box
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = StopDialog.create();
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `finish()` for `AlertDialog`. `finish()` refers to `Activity` class and will finish the current `Activity`. You should instead use `dismiss()`.

You can use the `DialogInterface` object like `dialog.dismiss()` to dismiss the `AlertDialog`.

You can go through the documentation for a broader idea :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html